# GTK - How to style a button in headerbar?

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to set color like blue and red in a application, is something like 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9bn8.jpg).

I imagine that I can do it with css styles, but if is there other way much more simple like set a property or a class.

I use GTK 3.12 and Python, but you can show me examples in other lenguages and I can traduce it.

Comment: I think you can't do it. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html 
Maybe you can solved creating a custom dialog for this

Comment: Is not for a dialog, really is for a custom Gtk.Window with header bar, but I want a blue button on the header bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do it is with the `suggested-action` and `destructive-action` CSS classes. [Here is some documentation.](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Buttons) Is there any particular objection that you have against CSS?

Use this code:

```
button.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_SUGGESTED_ACTION)
```

or

```
button.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_DESTRUCTIVE_ACTION)
```

before you add the button to the header bar.

Comment: Very good information, I will read these documentation, I don't use CSS because I want to respect the theme of the user and my buttons-made-with-css was looked very ugly